# Check for attribute on createElement returns false in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If I create a function that fires the following code on click, it returns `false`

```
'draggable' in document.createElement('div')
```

However, if I run this in the console, it returns `true`

Even switching 'draggable' to something as simple as 'style' yields the same results. Am I missing something?

## UPDATE

CoffeeScript's `in` blows away the default ECMA `in`, and you must use `of` instead.

Comment: _code on click, it returns false_ can you provide the code snippet, surely you might be doing something in the function, because `'draggable' in document.createElement('div')` simply returns whether this `draggable` property exists or not on created div

Comment: What returns false exactly? someElement.onclick = function(){'draggable' in document.createElement('div')} ?

Comment: How do you know that the expression results in `false`?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (returns true)

```
<html>

<script>function clickMe(){console.log('draggable' in document.createElement('div'));}</script>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:100px;" onClick="clickMe()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the initial programming language, CoffeeScript, which changes how `in` works by default. To obtain the same expected behavior, you need to use `of`.

```
'draggable' of document.createElement('div')
```

I'll update my question to be more clear for others who stumble upon this question.